# How do I capture a regex greedily based on a different situation?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, interpolation, string-interpolation

Currently, I am trying to implement string interpolation for my language.

The string interpolation looks something like this:

```
let x = " Baby"
let message = "Hello $(x)"
```

My current regex to capture interpolated expression is:

```
const regex = /[$][(].*?[)]/g;
```

However, the regex above works well with non-bracketed expressions, but it does not work properly when the interpolated expression have brackets, for example:

```
let message = "My number is $(square(1+2))"
// the captured group would be `$(square(1+2)` , which is missing a bracket
```

I could not use greedy quantifiers. If not it will not work when there is more than one interpolated expression, such as:

```
let message = "My number is $(x) $(y) $(z)"
// if capture greedily, it would be `$(x) $(y) $(z)`, which is not desired
```

How do I greedily capture interpolated expressions based on situations?

Note: I'm looking for answer in JavaScript.

Comment: In JS regex, you cannot match nested brackets.

Comment: I don't think even the new ES 2018 features add support for balanced capture or any other scheme for capturing things like that in a single run of the expression - I feel fairly confident you'll be well served to build a stateful parser that will find a `$(` then either the next `(` (and parse it further as a nested expression), or a `)` to signal the end of each nested expression

Comment: You really should attempt some minimal level of parsing.  Not everything is meant to fit inside a single regex.

Comment: I will say that if you know you only need to support nesting 2 or 3 deep (or maybe even up to 10? -- if you're really masochistic) then you can create multiple regex expressions for each case you want to support. But matching expressions with arbitrary nesting depth is prone to failure in countless ways in JavaScript

Comment: @JayC Yeap, I will try it because it does not seems too hard actually.

Comment: If these strings are separated by at least 1 whitespace then you may be able to use this regex: `/\$\(\S*\)/g`

Answer (score 0):

You can use template string (or literal string) like this

```js
let x = 1, y = 2, z = 3;
console.log(`Mu number ${x} ${y} ${z}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but your answer is too off-topic, because I was asking how to implement string interpolation, not how to use it.

Comment: Why do you need to re-implement it? it's a javascript core structure, always safer than your (or mine) code

Comment: Because I am creating my own programming language  my friend.

Comment: so, you can't do it with only regex. You have to implement an algorithm.. and you need to study regular language theory :)  and only a suggestion, i would not use js to implement an other languages.. few years i tried to do that by using c++

Comment: Actually I use TypeScript, which is a superset of JavaScript with strong typing and discriminated unions.

Comment: different...but same :)   they are both hight level languages. think about that

Answer (score 0):

Updated regex what you created, this will allow you to capture the second bracket it is there. Please find the following regex, btw I am not able to understand the third scenario. Test this regex and let me know if it fulfills your reqt. If not then elaborate on the third scenario and I will update my regex.

For scenario 3:

`'[$][(].*?[\)]+'` will capture `'$(x)' '$(y)' '$(z)'` differently. Mean to say match individually.

`'[$][(].*[\)]+'` will capture `'$(x) $(y) $(z)'` as one string. Whole string.

Please let me know if it works.